# index column type="timestamp" in solr from cassandra database

Tags: solr

Here i am using DSE-3.0.I want to index column type="timestamp" name="DateTime" in solr from cassandra database.What should be the fieldType in schema.xml in solr for type="timestamp".Please help me.I have badly need it.
           Thank you
This is my database output: --
cqlsh:mykeyspace> SELECT * FROM mysolr ;

KEY,124 | Date_Time,2013-02-11 10:10:10+0530 | body,A chicken in every pot ... | date,dec 15, 1933 | name,Roosevelt | title,fireside chat

But at query not gives value of Date_Time field.
My query output in solr is :--
id,body,title,name,date
124,A chicken in every pot ...,fireside chat,Roosevelt,"dec 15, 1933"

What am i missing to configure.Please guide me proper way. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In versions of Solr prior to 4.2 there was a `timestamp` field in the example [schema.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_1/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml?view=markup) that implemented a predefined `date` fieldType

```
 <field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW"      
      multiValued="false"/>
```

Here is the date fieldType definition

```
       <!-- The format for this date field is of the form 1995-12-31T23:59:59Z, and
         is a more restricted form of the canonical representation of dateTime
         http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime    
         The trailing "Z" designates UTC time and is mandatory.
         Optional fractional seconds are allowed: 1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z
         All other components are mandatory.

         Expressions can also be used to denote calculations that should be
         performed relative to "NOW" to determine the value, ie...

               NOW/HOUR
                  ... Round to the start of the current hour
               NOW-1DAY
                  ... Exactly 1 day prior to now
               NOW/DAY+6MONTHS+3DAYS
                  ... 6 months and 3 days in the future from the start of
                      the current day

         Consult the DateField javadocs for more information.

         Note: For faster range queries, consider the tdate type
      -->
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

So based on this example, I would recommend using the date field type, noting that it will be stored in UTC format.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable support But,You get it in wrong way.I have a cassandra column family and in that family i have a column-name="Date_Time" type="timestamp".Now,how can i index it into solr schema.xml?Is there any fieldType in solr for timestamp.According to you my schema.xml will be like this <fieldType name="timestamp" class="solr.DateField"/> and <field name="Date_Time" type="timestamp" stored="true" indexed="true"/>.But sorry to say that it gives error. like this.....Current Validation Class and solrType do not found for column family:Date_Time.

Comment: The example I have shown is the standard way for defining a timestamp field within Solr. The "Current Validation Class and solrType" error is not a standard Solr error, that you are seeing. I believe this is related to DataStax Enterprise. I would suggest posting something on thier support forums - https://support.datastax.com/home